# Off-delay timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, race-condition

Is there a way to write a safe one-second off-delay timer class in C# using exactly one System.Threading.Timer object?

Alternatively, what would be the simplest solution in general, assuming the input can get turned on and off a lot faster than once per second?

An off-delay timer could be described by this interface:

```
public interface IOffDelay
{
    /// <summary>
    /// May be set to any value from any thread.
    /// </summary>
    bool Input { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whenever Input is true, Output is also true.
    /// The Output is only false at startup
    /// or after the Input has been continuously off for at least 1 second.
    /// </summary>
    bool Output { get; }
}
```

This is my first attempt:

```
public sealed class OffDelay : IOffDelay, IDisposable
{
    public OffDelay()
    {
        timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer.Dispose();
    }

    public bool Input
    {
        get
        {
            lock (locker)
                return _input;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (value == _input)
                    return;

                _input = value;

                if (_input == false)
                    timer.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
                else
                {
                    _output = true;
                    timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private bool _input;

    public bool Output
    {
        get
        {
            lock (locker)
                return _output;
        }
    }
    private bool _output;

    private readonly Timer timer;
    private readonly object locker = new object();

    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        lock (locker)
            _output = false;
    }
}
```

I can see that there is a race condition in this solution:

1. At the end of a one-second off period, the timer schedules the callback to run.
2. Someone quickly sets and resets the input, restarting the timer.
3. The callback now finally runs, checks the input and sets the output to false even though it should be true for another second.

#### Edit

Peter Duniho provided the correct answer, but it turns out I'm terrible at asking the right question. The OffDelay class should also do some operation when the output changes to false. Here is the modified code adapting Peter's basic principle:

```
public sealed class OffDelay : IOffDelay, IDisposable
{
    public OffDelay()
    {
        timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer.Dispose();
    }

    public bool Input
    {
        get
        {
            lock (locker)
                return _input;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (value == _input)
                    return;

                _input = value;

                if (_input == true)
                    _output = true;
                else
                {
                    stopwatch.Restart();
                    if (!timerRunning)
                        timer.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private bool _input;

    public bool Output
    {
        get
        {
            lock (locker)
                return _output;
        }
    }
    private bool _output;

    private readonly object locker = new object();
    private readonly Timer timer;
    private readonly Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    private bool timerRunning;

    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (_input == true)
                timerRunning = false;
            else
            {
                var remainingTimeMs = 1000 - stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                if (remainingTimeMs > 0)
                    timer.Change(remainingTimeMs, Timeout.Infinite);
                else
                {
                    _output = false;
                    timerRunning = false;
                    DoSomething();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the question, including showing exactly what the context is and what constraints might exist, it's impossible to know for sure what answer would work for you.

But based on what you've included in your question, I would change your implementation so it doesn't rely on the timer:

```
public sealed class OffDelay : IOffDelay
{
    public bool Input
    {
        get { lock (locker) return _input; }
        set
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (value == _input)
                    return;

                _input = value;
                _lastInput = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
        }
    }
    private bool _input;

    public bool Output
    {
        get { lock (locker) return (DateTime.UtcNOw - _lastInput).TotalSeconds < 1; }
    }
    private DateTime _lastInput;
}
```

Note that the above is susceptible to clock changes on the computer. If you have a need to work independently of the clock, you can replace `DateTime.UtcNow` with a `Stopwatch` instance, call `Reset()` on each change to the `Input` property, and use the `Elapsed` property of the `Stopwatch` to determine the length of time since last input.

Comment: I was trying to avoid unnecessary complications in the posted question, but I guess I have accidentally left out a crucial part: I the class needs to do something when the output changes to false. Your answer is the correct one for the question asked, though, and it provided me with the hint needed for the real solution.